# a coin toss and a die roll simultaneously

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that we toss a fair coin and, then toss a fair four-sided die.

(a) Defne the sample space for this experiment.

(b) Let $X$ be the random variable defined as (number of heads) + (die score modulus 2). Identify the possible values $x$ that $X$ can have, and write down the event $X = x$ for each value of $x$. Then calculate the probability mass function for $X$.

**Solution:**
(a) For the coin toss, there are two possible outcomes head(H) and tail(T).

For the four-sided die roll there are four possible outcomes $1,2,3,4$.

So, the sample space is $\{(H,1),(H,2),(H,3),(H,4),(T,1),(T,2),(T,3),(T,4)\}$.

I am unable to understand the problem (b). It says that $X$ be the random variable defined as (number of heads) + (die score modulus 2). But there are only one head with die score $2$. that is $(H,2)$. Is it ? I think I am not correct. What does it mean actually? and how to solve this?

Comment: You can have either $0$ or $1$ heads from the coin flip and the four-sided die can give you either $0$ or $1 \pmod 2$.

Comment: Example: you toss the coin and roll the die. The coin comes up tails. The die comes up 3. Then (number of heads) = 0, and (die score modulus 2) = 1. Thus the value of $X$ is $0 + 1 = 1$. You can do this for all coin and die outcomes. ("Die score modulus 2" means "the remainder when dividing the die score by 2", so a die score of 1 gives you 1, a die score of 2 gives you 0, a die score of 3 gives you 1, a die score of 4 gives you 0. Normally we would use the world "modulo" here, not "modulus".)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the sample space is $\Omega=\{H,T\}\times\{1,2,3,4\}$.

For (b) it is simpler to write $X=Y+Z$ where $Y$ is the number of heads and $Z$ the die score mod $2$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(Y=0) = \frac12=\mathbb P(Y=1)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(Z=0)=\frac12=\mathbb P(Z=1)
$$
(note that $Z=0$ when the die rolls $2$ or $4$ and $Z=1$ when the die rolls $1$ or $3$). By independence of $Y$ and $Z$ we have
$$
\mathbb P(X=k) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb P(Y=0)\mathbb P(Z=0) = \frac14,& k=0\\
\mathbb P(Y=0)\mathbb P(Z=1)+ \mathbb P(Y=1)\mathbb P(Z=0) = \frac12, & k=1\\
\mathbb P(Y=1)\mathbb P(Z=1) = \frac14,& k=2.
\end{cases}
$$